# Should Screen Reader reads "Home, Link, Menu Item" or "Home, Menu Item"

Tags: html, menu, accessibility, screen-readers

If the menu items are links, should the screen reader read it as "home, link, menu item" or "home, menu item"?

Currently the screen reader is reading it as "home, link, menu item" but I am getting mixed information about it. Some information says it should be "home, link, menu item" because we want users to know the button is a link. However, some say that it should just be announced as "home, menu item"

Here's my code:

```
<ul role="menu">
        <li role="menuitem">
            <a aria-label="Home" href="/en-us/">
                <span class="">Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem">
            <a aria-label="Search" href="/en-us/">
                <span class="">Search</span>
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

I was wondering which version is correct?

Comment: Unless your menu is an OS-style popup menu, you shouldn't be using role=menu/menuitem. In particular, you shouldn't use these roles for website classic menus. Using role=menu/menuitem implies that you correctly react to arrow keys, enter and escape, what you probably don't.

Comment: @QuentinC what should I use instead if i don't use menu/menuitem?

Comment: Don't use any role. The implicit roles for  `<ul>` and `<li>` are perfectly satisfactory in most cases for website menus. Remember the golden rule of ARIA: use it only if you really need to.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for more opinions, because there are no hard and fast rules as to how things "should" be read. That's between you and your customers that use screen readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your html is correct, then don't worry about how the screen reader announces it.  JAWS, NVDA, VoiceOver, Talkback, Narrator, ChromeVox, etc may all announce it slightly different and that's ok.  As long as the code is correct, then you're good.

As a side note, if you use the menu roles, then you are committing to implementing arrow key navigation.  That is, think of the menu role as an old school desktop app menu where you can press <kbd>alt</kbd> to get to the top menu (such as file, edit, view) and then left/right arrows to navigate through the menu and up/down arrows to navigate through the submenu.  It's fine to do that on a web application but it makes the code more complicated.  I rarely use the menu roles and just rely on basic tabbing to navigate through a list of links.

Answer (score 3):

Just for anyone who stumbles across this, `aria-role="menu"` and `aria-role="menu-item"` are **not** for site navigation (as appears to be the case here).

They are designed for application menus (such as drop downs with commands).

For site navigation the correct (and much simpler) mark-up is to simply use the `<nav>` element with a nested `<ul>` (unless you are supporting HTML4...and even then the `<ul>` would probably be enough!).

Additionally there is no real need for an `aria-label` in the above given examples  as the `aria-label` is the same as the programatically determinable text (a web browser can work out that the "Home" text is within the `<a>` element and so will present that information to a screen reader via the accessibility tree).

As such for site navigation the following is all that is needed:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/en-us/">
        <span class="">Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/en-us/">
        <span class="">Search</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Don't use WAI-ARIA unless you have explored every other option or you need to support ancient browsers!**

### Additional

With `aria-role="menu"` you don't only have to implement arrow key navigation. You also should have functionality added that ensure that:-

- the menu can be closed with <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.
- you can skip to options using letters (so <kbd>d</kbd> might skip to "details", the next press of <kbd>d</kbd> might skip to "delete" if those were menu options).
- <kbd>Home</kbd> should jump to the start of the list
- <kbd>End</kbd> should jump to the last item in the list

#### Finally

If this is indeed a drop down menu and you have implemented all the above, your mark-up isn't *quite* right anyway.

The `<li>` should have `role="presentation none"` ([use both "presentation" **and** "none" as per guidance](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#none)) to remove semantic meaning and the `role="menu-item"` should be on the anchor itself.

```html
<ul role="menu" id="some-menu">
  <li role="presentation none">
    <a role="menuitem" aria-label="Home" href="/en-us/">
      <span class="">Home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation none">
    <a role="menuitem" aria-label="Search" href="/en-us/">
      <span class="">Search</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also don't forget that you need to associate the `<button>` that opened the menu with the menu itself, so you **must** have an ID on the `role="menu"`, and finally don't forget that when the menu is closed you have to return focus to the button that opened it.

```html
<button aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="some-menu"><!--same ID as the menu above for aria-controls-->
   Open Menu 
</button>
```